# How to export message box display data in excel to access database table using vba

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I have a code in vba through which whenever i will  save any new value in a particular cell it will show in the message box that what was the old value stored in the cell and what was the new value which i have just saved below is the code for that

```
Option Explicit

Dim OldVals As New Dictionary

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim myCell As Range

    For Each myCell In Target
        If OldVals.Exists(myCell.Address) Then
           MsgBox "New value of " & Replace(myCell.Address, "$", "") & " is " & myCell.Value & "; old value was " & OldVals(myCell.Address)
        Else
           MsgBox "No old value for " + Replace(myCell.Address, "$", "")
        End If
        OldVals(myCell.Address) = myCell.Value
    Next myCell

End Sub
```

**the output window of the code will come like this in the picture below --**
[image]

**so i want to export the values which was displayed in the message box to the access database table using vba one after the another**

however i have written a code to export and save the values of excel sheet cells into access database table the code is below

```
Const TARGET_DB = "\Database3.accdb"
    Sub PushTableToAccess()
    Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim MyConn
    Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim Rw As Long

    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Rw = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

    Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
    MyConn = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & TARGET_DB

    With cnn
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    .Open MyConn
    End With



    Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
    rst.CursorLocation = adUseServer
    rst.Open Source:="Table1", ActiveConnection:=cnn, _
    CursorType:=adOpenDynamic, LockType:=adLockOptimistic, _
    Options:=adCmdTable

    For i = 2 To Rw
        rst.AddNew
        For j = 1 To 3
            rst(j) = Cells(i, j).Value
        Next j
        rst.Update
    Next i


    rst.Close
    cnn.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set cnn = Nothing

    End Sub
```

the above code will export and save all the values in excel cells to access database table .

but i am not sure how to combine both the codes so that  my first code whenever it will display the old and new values of cell and when i click on OK button it will export and save the value displayed in message box **(eg- new value of  A1 is 7 ; old value was 88)**  to access database table one after the another .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want to make an audit/logging function of all changes to a an Excel workbook.

You have two pieces of code, one to identify the change and one to write information to a datbase, an you want to combine this. The resulting functionality wold then be to write every change the user makes to a database.

The code you have should give you enough guidance on the particular VBA statements. I'll limit this solution to the approach.

As you will need the database connection during the whole time the user has the worksheet opened, you should make the database connection in the Workbook Open event:

```
Public cnn As ADODB.Connection
Public MyConn

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
    MyConn = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & TARGET_DB
    With cnn
        .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
        .Open MyConn
    End With
End Sub
```

Then you continue in the Change events:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    '.... (your code to get the change)

    Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset

    rst.AddNew                     ' allocate new record
    rst(j) = Cells(i, j).Value     ' populate the record (this must be your code)
    rst.Update                     ' update/insert record
    rst.Close                      ' done record.
End Sub
```

Finally you close the database in the Workbook_BeforeClose event.